# Who first invented barrier blocks and when?

Tags: connector, history

I get the sense that the Buchanan Construction Company made the first [barrier blocks](https://www.digikey.com/short/19r52nqz) but I can't get much info on that. Ideal bought Buchanan and that history seems to be lost. Also, TE sells barrier blocks under the "Buchanan" name.

[image: Barrier block]

{Source: me}

Edit: Molex invented [the first power-distribution terminal block in a molded housing](https://history.molex.com/) in 1945. But it's a terminal block (has wire cages) not a barrier block (plain screws). I don't know if the barrier block came before or after this terminal block.

[image: Molex terminal block]

{Source: Molex}

EDIT: a patent search found [US patent 1517017 by Raymond T Roth, "Terminal block"](https://patents.google.com/patent/US1517017A/en). This is clearly the right concept, but not yet the shape of the barrier blocks we're familiar with.

[image: US Patent 1517017]

{Source: Google patents}

So I am asking for leads from this community.

(This is for a book I'm writing.)

Comment: probably someone in their garage ... repeated more than once

Comment: I think most people call them "terminal blocks".

Comment: No, I am not asking about [terminal blocks](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/category/terminal-blocks/2030). I am asking about [barrier blocks](https://www.digikey.com/short/19r52nqz). They're different beasts. Barrier blocks use screws. Terminal blocks uses wire cages.

Comment: Best bet is to do a patent search for this info.

Comment: Cinch-Jones comes to mind. History of [Cinch](https://www.belfuse.com/resources/Brochures/CinchConnectivitySolutions/CompanyBrochures/br-CCS-Cinch100Story.pdf) goes back to 1917. I doubt that they were the first, but one of the early innovators.

Comment: Wikipedia describes them as [barrier strips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_terminal_block)

Comment: I call them choc blocks <-- is that what you mean?

Comment: @Andy aka  "choc blocks" are [Europa Style terminal strips](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=eurostyle_terminal_strips). "choc" stand for "chocolate" because of the way you can break as strip as long as you need. Anyway, they are terminal blocks, not barrier blocks. I am asking about barrier blocks.

Comment: @Finbarr, Yes, that's what I am asking about. Trying to find leads on their history.

Comment: @qrk That is a good lead, thank you. Probably Jones, not Cinch. Cinch bough Jones in 1946, and I think that barrier blocks are older than that.  I am exploring it now.

Comment: @qrk I found a 1959 Cinch Jones catalog that lists Screw type terminal strips”. Thank's promising.

Comment: In the barrier block link you provided, many of the items listed were choc blocks so, maybe you need to be more specific next time (if re-opened). For instance, [this item from FEC](https://uk.farnell.com/phoenix-contact/ec-6/terminal-block-barrier-24pos-10awg/dp/3259533) is described as a barrier terminal block but, falls under the choc block umbrella as far as  I can tell. I know why choc blocks are called choc blocks.

Comment: @Andy aka.  Here is again [the link I provided](https://www.digikey.com/short/19r52nqz). I checked again, and they are all barrier blocks, no "chock blocks". The "chock blocks" are [here](https://www.digikey.com/short/pwv72r5q).

Comment: Why was this closed? Given that "barrier blocks" are commonly understood to refer to a specific form of terminal block, there will be one company that first produced them, a fact not an opinion.

Comment: @TimWilliams so perhaps history, but not a problem of electrical design.

Comment: @SolarMike So the "history" tag should be removed? It doesn't seem like most any question there would be a matter of active design work. Maybe EE is broader than that.